# Data type mismatch in criteria expression adding data to access table from datagridview

Tags: database, datagridview, mismatch

I can't seem to get my code to work. I keep getting a 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to add all contents in my datagridview to access table. Here is my code.

```
Dim connect As New OleDbConnection
connect.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=../Database.mdb")
connect.Open()

Dim str As String
str = "DELETE * FROM Tickets"
Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connect)

cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmdd.Dispose()

Dim AssignedCSR, Network, TicketNumber, DateReceived As String
For p as Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
   AssignedCSR = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
   Network = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
   TicketNumber = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
   DateReceived = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(3).Value.ToString()

   str = "INSERT INTO Tickets(AssignedCSR,Network,TicketNumber,DateReceived) VALUES('" & AssignedCSR & "','" & Network & "','" & TicketNumber & "','" & DateReceived & "')"
   cmdd = New OleDbCommand(str, connect)
   cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery 'This is where I am getting the error
   cmdd.Dispose()
Next
connect.Close()
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of each of the destination fields in the Access table?  There's probably either a mismatch between the table fields and what you're trying to insert or the insert syntax itself. If I had to guess, without looking at it, the last part of your statement should look like this:  & "', #" & DateReceived & "#)"  because Access/Jet SQL escapes dates with a pound sign, not single quotes.

Comment: the datatypes are short text, short text, short text, and date/time  EDIT: I changed what you mentioned and its still giving me the same error

Comment: print the contents of the variable str and let's take a look at them.

Comment: I did that in a msgbox and this is what I got
    INSERT INTO
    Tickets(AssignedCSR,Network,TicketNumber,DateReceived)
    VALUES('testname','testnetwork','testticket',#2/9/2015#)

Comment: I'm sure this has to do with how the date is being handled, but the solution escapes me at the moment. Try declaring DateReceived as a Date instead of a string.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Is there any way I can send you the project files so you can take a look at it better?

Comment: Here is the link for my project.
"http://wikisend.com/download/480666/S6 Database.rar"
It would be awesome if you could take a look at it! :)
The issue I am having is in the Search.vb form at the very bottom..

Comment: This is a bit tricky. I can't find it right away. If no one else posts,  I'll take a look when I get home from work tonight (USA Central Time)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!! I will try to figure it out in the meantime!